# LOAD DATA INFILE NULL are enclosed not loaded

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a CSV file that I exported from Oracle database. All the integer columns are not enclosed, but all the string columns are enclosed with `"`

I'm using MySQL 8. So I used the following command to import that file.

### Mysql Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE M_2 (
ID DECIMAL(19,0) NOT NULL,
CO1 VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
CO2 VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
CO3 VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
CO4 VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
CO5 VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
CO6 VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
CO7 VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

### Sample CSV data:

```
4914,"D","CA08196_BPB","PB","CA0836","L0810","",""
4936,"D","CA08194_KA1L","1L","CA0584","L0851","",""
4971,"D","CA08191_KA2","K2","CA0841","L0815","",""
4985,"D","CA08191_BPB","BB","CA0861","L0818","",""
```

### Load command:

```
 load data   infile '/var/lib/mysql-files/M_2.csv' 
into table M_2 
fields terminated by ',' 
 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
lines terminated by '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES ;
```

### Warnings in loading:

```
 Warning 
ERROR CODE: 1287 
'COM_FIELD_LIST' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SHOW COLUMNS FROM statement instead
```

But it didn't consider the NULL Values in `,""`  it loaded the next row into the next column.

### After importing:

[image]

Comment: Do you think seeing your target table definition might be useful?

Comment: @mustaccio question updated with the table schema

Comment: Did you verify the lines to end in **\n**, not **\r\n**?

Comment: The line ending is CRLF

Comment: Try with `lines terminated by '\r\n' `